# Github pages not showing react app website correctly

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, mixed-content

I am a self-taught programming newbie with 1 month of learning age.
Currently I have built a project by watching youtube and I want to show the project results on github page, but after trying everything the website still fails to correctly show the contents of the web, only showing the readme.md as the page content.

1. This is my project: https://github.com/PerdidoenCoding/first_react_app
2. This is my github page URL: https://perdidoencoding.github.io/first_react_app/

After numerous tries, finally found the error as to why it was showing readme.md file instead of the correct website. I did not install the gh-pages package.
After correctly installing the gh-pages packages and running
npm run deploy,the website is finally showing, but the website is not running the API_URL function in my website, which I got from omdbapi, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `API_URL` is being served using `http` whilst Github pages are served using `https` protocol, leading to `mixed content error`, which is caused when sites served from `https` are fetching insecure resources (images, scripts, APIs, etc.). Changing it to `https` should load the data you`re expecting from.

You can read more about mixed content here ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content))

Note that in your current state, you are getting a network error when trying to fetch the API, which you are not handling, so I would also wrap your `setMovies` contents in a try/catch and provide a fallback or notify the user about the issues. What if the API is actually down? It's not actually correct to display that there are no movies for Batman.

Comment: Thank you so much! The tip to configure setMovies contents is also brilliant, as I am really new to this, I would need to think how to do that or to find help for doing that. First I will try to change the API_URL to https and try making the website show correctly in Github pages

Comment: @Perdido you would have to wrap what you have in a try/catch block, you need to think what to show to the user when you have an error reaching that API. As I can see you are a new Stack Overflow user, I want to add that it's good practice to upvote/accept answers if you've found it useful.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to everything actually. I have just accepted your answer as it worked perfectly and will research on what you just said because I don't fully understand the topic just yet!